# Double Cipher Challenge

Tags: cipher

This is a challenge for those who wish to go two deep.
The code below is obviously done in some version of pigpen.  The pigpen is quite straight forward by example.
It has also been Cesar ciphered.

You figure out how to apply those and when.

Two words with no spaces.

A hug and a couple kisses for the first solver!!

HERE IT IS:
[image]
Try to ignore the cut-n-paste job...

Comment: Are you sure the pigpen is correct? The result for me doesn't ceasar shift to anything meaniful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Pigpen Cipher gives:

> jcrravjcpmuikxkpiyqy

With Caesar Cipher

> Shifting -2
> happythanksgivingwow

The Answer:

> Happy Thanksgiving WOW

The decoding gives:

> jciiavjcpmuikxkpiyqy
> Haggy Thanksgiving WOW

Comment: Note that you've transcribed it incorrectly from the question: where you got the first two r's are actually meant to be i according to the question, or am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe Dr1 wrote some error letters

Comment: @yass. You got it right.  You did get the hug "O" but not the kisses because I messed up the cipher.  Should have ended with "XOX" which is 'kiss', 'hug', 'kiss'